# Best way to strip invalid json characters from json like string before unmarshal

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling, utf

To give some background, I am reading device logs from android and ios devices using adb logcat and idevicesyslog.  The specific logs I am after are swift/c#/java/etc dictionaries converted to strings via adb logcat / idevicesyslog.  I hope to take these logs that contain JSON like strings and convert those to valid JSON.  This works for the most part no problem.

However, sometimes these logs/string outputs contain characters like (\134, \M, \t, etc etc) that cause issues when unmarshalling into JSON.  I unmarshal them to JSON to send them elsewhere.

For example a raw device log may have something like the following:
{"foo":"bar","foo":"bar\134/\134/bar\134/bar\134/bar"}
{"foo":"bar","foo":"bar\M/\134/bar\134/bar\M/bar"}

These result in errors like "panic: invalid character 'M' in string escape code" when attempting to unmarshal

The majority of logs do not contain these characters and so it's not a problem. However, a few edge cases contain these and it creates problems.

Is there a proper name for these types of characters? (c# escape characters?) Is there a golang package that can remove them from a string?  Currently, I am just deleting the specific ones i come across if they appear in a string but I feel like there's a better way to do it. Adding the ones I come across to a list of deletable characters is not a good practice.

To summarize,

idevicesyslog log gives me a string like so:
{"foo":"bar","foo":"bar\134/\134/bar\134/bar\134/bar"}

This can not be unmarshalled.

idevicesyslog log gives me a string like so:
{"foo":"bar","foo":"bar bar bar bar"}

This can be unmarshalled.

Current solution: add new ones I come across to a list and remove them before unmarshaling

Hopeful solution: detect automatically and remove

Comment: It looks like the text contains invalid JSON escape sequences.  That's different from containing non utf8 text.  It's unclear what you want to remove.  Is it sufficient to remove the backslash, the backslash and following character, or something else?  Give examples of the source string and the string you want to convert it to.   To avoid confusion, describe the format of the strings.  For example, are they printed with fmt.Sprintf("%s", s), fmt.Sprintf("%q", s) or something else?

Comment: I think they are these characters (from a list of c# escape characters) that are part of the string received from the output of idevicesyslog (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/docs/idevicesyslog.1)

I do not control the printing of the string but rather filter out the logs i want from idevicesyslog / adb logcat. Examples i've seen are \047 single quote \134 backslash \140 grave accent

Comment: as libimobiledevice is written in "c" they use "fprintf" or "fflush" i believe

Comment: In the case of "\047", does the string contain the bytes 92, 48, 52, 55?  Is your goal to replace these four bytes with the single byte 47 (single quote)?

Comment: My goal is to replace them with characters that do not cause unmarshalling errors.  So i guess replacing them all with empty string. However, I wasn't sure if there was a built in package to do this. Otherwise, I have to compile a list and do a search and replace on each log that contains "these characters". If i compile the list myself that is prone to errors as I don't know all that exist.

Comment: The problem is invalid escape sequences, not invalid characters. It seems like your goal is to convert the escaping from whatever produced this text to valid JSON escape sequences.  There are no invalid characters in the test shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, that seems right.  The error I get is "panic: invalid character '\134' in string escape code" when unmarshaling to json. I convert the string to a []byte and unmarshal:

     `err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &metadataMap)`

Comment: If the escapes were all like `\nnn` (i.e. C-like octal escapes) then I'd suggest using a regex replace of a backslash followed by three digits, but the presence of `\M` means that won't work for all strings, and in fact that isn't a standard escape that I've come across, so you may need to just maintain a list of escapes you need to replace.

Comment: Yeah, this conversation with you both has been helpful and I'm thinking that what I dreaded (e.g. keeping track and replacing each) is what I will need to do.  Either that or rewrite these open source device loggers in go.  Currently using something like this (when \134 was the only one causing problems):

`func replaceSpChar(s string) string {

 var jsonStr = s

 specialChar := strings.Contains(jsonStr, `\134`)

 if specialChar {
  jsonStr = strings.Replace(jsonStr, `\134`, "", -1)
 }

 return jsonStr
}`

would just need to create a list of all.

Comment: I think maybe just replacing all "\" with "\\" might be realistic as well:

`strings.Replace(str, "\\", "\\\\", -1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regexp to replace the invalid octal escape sequences with a space:

```
var octalEscapePat = regexp.MustCompile(`\\[0-7]{3}`)

func fix(src string) string {
    return octalEscapePat.ReplaceAllString(src, " ")
}
```

You can also parse the octal value and convert to a valid JSON escape sequence:

```
func fix(src string) string {
    return octalEscapePat.ReplaceAllStringFunc(src, func(s string) string {
        // Parse octal value
        n, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s[1:], 8, 0)
        // Convert to string and marshal to JSON to handle any escaping
        b, _ := json.Marshal(string(n))
        // return string with surrounding quotes removed
        return string(b[1 : len(b)-1])
    })
}
```

The \M can be handled in a similar way.

https://play.golang.org/p/-gtxrvnBSrx

Comment: Nice. Thanks!  One thing I noticed is that the majority of these "octal escapes" occur with url data. 

e.g. 
"https:\134/\134/foo.net\134/i\134/bar\134/foo\134/bar\134/m3u8\134/300\134/master.m3u8"

Comment: @Steve The source application is escaping forward slash for some reason. That's not needed.  Use regexp `\`\\134/\`` and replace with `"/"` to fix this.

Comment: Was able to find issue here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10218

Possible solutioning (although in dart):
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/14075/files

Comment: The Dart code has good documentation on the format you are dealing with and should be easy to translate to Go.